# Properly or strictly separated sets

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $A=\{ x,y,z: x,y,z\in[0,1] \}$ and $B=\{(x-2)^{2}+(y-2)^{2}+(z-2)^{2}\le 1\}$. Show if the sets $A$ and $B$ can be properly or strictly separated. Does anyone know the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set a $A$ is a cube with side $1$, the set $B$ is a ball with radius $1$. The sets $A$ and $B$ are closed compacts. The sets $A$ are $B$ disjoint because if $(x,y,z)\in A$ then $(x-2)^2\ge 1$, $(y-2)^2\ge 1$, and $(z-2)^2\ge 1$, therefore $(x,y,z)\not\in B$. Thus, by [Hahn-Banach separation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems), the sets $A$ and $B$ can be separated.

Comment: I understand, but I am supposed to find also the separating hyperplane, that is, to find the corresponding normal vector.

Comment: @Laura This should be done with a bit of geometric imagination. In general it should be a hyperplane going through an interior point of a segment realizing the minimal distance between the sets $A$ and $B$ and perpendicular to the segment. In this partial case it seems that the segment is $$[(1,1,1), (2-\frac 1{\sqrt{3}},2-\frac 1{\sqrt{3}},2-\frac 1{\sqrt{3}})],$$ so it suffices to take a hyperplane $x+y+z=c$ for any $c\in (3, 6-\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could I ask you what about in case that we have the sets $A=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}:xy\ge 2 \}$. What would be the normal vector of the separating hyperplane?

Comment: @Laura This becomes clear when we draw a picture of $A$ and $B$. As a separating hyperplane we can take a line $\ell$ described by the equation $x+y=c$  (so with the normal vector $(1,1)$) for any $c\in (2, 2\sqrt{2})$. We can easily verify analytically that $\ell$ separates $A$ and $B$. Indeed, if $(x,y)\in A$ then $x,y\le 1$ so $x+y\le 2<c$. If $(x,y)\in B$ then $xy\ge 2$ and by the inequality between arithmetic and geometric means we have $x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}\ge 2\sqrt{2}>c$.

Comment: It makes sense, however, I read that for the normal vector $\alpha$ must be fulfilled $\inf <\alpha, a> \ge \sup <\alpha,b>, a\in A, b\in B$. By $<,>$ I mean a scalar product. It does not work for $\alpha =(1,1)$.

Comment: @Laura It works the converse way, $\sup_{a\in A} \langle a, \alpha\rangle=2<2\sqrt{2}=\inf_{b\in B} \langle b, \alpha\rangle$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. And last thing, sorry for bothering you, would you know how to describe the closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as a intersection of supporting halfspaces?

Comment: @Laura Let $B$ be a closed ball of in $\Bbb R^n$ of positive radius $R$ centered at a point $x_0\in\Bbb R^n$. Then $B=\bigcap_{x\in S} H_x$,  where $S$ is the sphere bounding $B$, and $H_x=\{y\in\Bbb R^n: \langle x-x_0,y-x_0\rangle\le R^2\}$ is a half-space supporting $B$ at $x$.

Comment: Could you explain in more details why the half-space supporting $B$ at $x$ is the $H_{x}$ set? I would say that a tangent plane to the sphere at point $x$ is the equation $<x-x_{0},y-x>=0$ so $H_{x}=\{ y\in\mathbb {R}^{n}:<x-x_{0},y-x>\le 0\}$. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @Laura This condition defines the same set $H_x$, because $\langle x−x_0,y−x_0\rangle \le R^2$ iff $\langle x−x_0,y−x\rangle \le 0$ (since $\langle x−x_0,x−x_0\rangle=R^2$.

Comment: Ok, it's really true. Just one more question about the sign. The hyperplane is divided in two half spaces and how we know which of the sign $\leq$ or $\geq$ is correct for the general point $x$? I mean the hyperplane $\langle x-x_{0},y-x\rangle =0$ is the same as $\langle x_{0}-x,y-x\rangle=0$ so we are supposed to write that the half-space supporting $B$ at $x$ is either $H_{x}=\{y\in\mathbb R^{n}:\langle x-x_{0},y-x\rangle\le 0\}$ or $H_{x}=\{y\in\mathbb R^{n}:\langle x_{0}-x,y-x\rangle\ge 0 \}$. Why not for example  $H_{x}=\{y\in\mathbb R^{n}:\langle x-x_{0},y-x\rangle\ge 0\}$?

Comment: @Laura I guess you mean “The *space $\Bbb R^n$* is divided into two half spaces”. We choose the sign for the expression determining $H_x$ to assure that $H_x$ contains $x_0$. Since $\langle x−x_0,x_0−x\rangle=\langle x−x_0,x-x_0\rangle=-R^2\le 0$, we should impose the condition $\langle x−x_0,y−x\rangle \le 0$.